# Angular 2 data grid (table) with grouping of rows against (by) column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need a data grid for Angular 2 project that supports grouping like in http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-grouping.htm. The user should be able to drag and drop columns to do the grouping. Seems like the ag-grid and primeNG and many other options do not support this feature. Does anyone know a good one? Some features I need are collapsable groups and group by multiple columns.

Comment: thi is probably possible with ag-grid with a bit of work on your own. You can update colsDef and data while the grid is active and reload it so you can change the grouping according to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG 1.1 has row grouping; https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/403